# Update Data in Real Time when getting from server into RecylerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, java-websocket

I am getting json from Websockets and showing in recyler view. How do i update the list in real time when getting data from websockets?

> My WebSocket Class

```
 public final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
    private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
    private static final String TAG = "DashBoardScreen.this";

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
```

*initially when connection is established i send some text to server*

```
  webSocket.send(builder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
```

*in return server sends me data*

```
 output(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClosing: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t,Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
    }
}
```

> Output Method

```
 private void output(final String text) {

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             *parsing json inside recyler view*

                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(text);
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        if (object.getBoolean("status")) {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("events");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject values = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                final EventsDataModel dataModel = new EventsDataModel(
                                        values.getString("service_Room_Number"),
                                        values.getString("service_Name"),
                                        values.getString("service_AssignedTo"),
                                        values.getString("service_ID")
                                );                       
                                eventsDataModels.add(dataModel);
                                adapter = new EventListAdapter(eventsDataModels, context);
                                eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*how exactly notifyDataSetChanged() works?*

```
                            }
                        } else Toast.makeText(context, "No Events", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println(builder.append(object.getString("status")));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904395/6401241

Comment: ok..understood.

Comment: @Radesh it is not working in my case

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your dataModel has the new data

`eventsDataModels.add(dataModel);
adapter = new EventListAdapter(eventsDataModels, context);
eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

If you perform the above operations and performing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
Will notify the adapter the new data has arrived and have to update the RecyclerView with new dataModel.

Comment: But..why it is not working in my case? not showing updated list

Comment: did you debug and see that data is changing in dataModel?

Comment: Add this code after the for loop ends                                                             adapter = new EventListAdapter(eventsDataModels, context);
                                eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Hence, for now my datamodel size is not increasing or decreasing when getting response from server but the values are changing..datamodel is same.

Comment: Check this for guidance https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-fetch-json-data-using-volley-and-put-it-to-recyclerview-android-studio-383059a12d1e

Comment: I am using websockets here not REST.